# Find intersection point of two straight lines

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to find the intersection point of two lines where, one of the lines is parallel to y axis.
I know we can find the intersection point of two line by solving the equation $y=m(x-P_x)+P_y$
where m is the slope 
and $(P_x,P_y)$ are the given coordinates.

but when the line is parallel to y axis, its slope is not defined. In that case, how to solve the equations and how to find the angle between those two lines?

Comment: What are the equations of the two lines? Also, if there is no defined slope (parallel to y-axis), then the equation of that line is of the form $x=c$ for some constant $c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the general form $Ax + By + C = 0$ and $A_2x + B_2y + C_2 = 0$

Then the point of intersection will be $(\frac{B*C_2 - B_2*C_1}{A*B_2-A_2*B} , \frac{C*A_2 - A_1*C_2}{A*B_2-A_2*B})$

Now take $B_2$ as zero because line is parallel to y-axis.

Thus the new point of intersection will be $(\frac{B*C_2}{-A_2*B} , \frac{C*A_2 - A_1*C_2}{-A_2*B})$ = $(\frac{-C_2}{A_2} , \frac{A_1*C_2 -C*A_2}{A_2*B})$

And to find the angle between those two lines.
[image]

Comment: Thank you! Solves my purpose.

Comment: Can you help me find the angle between the two lines?

Comment: Let the angle be $\theta$, and slope of the lines be $m_1$ and $m_2$. Then $Tan(\theta) = (\frac{m_1 - m_2 }{1 + m_1*m_2})$ or $(\frac{m_2 - m_1}{1 + m_1*m_2})$

Comment: But slope of a vertical line is not defined. How can we find the angle in that case.

Comment: @monica check now.

Comment: Nice explanation. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thanks :), anyway Can you now find the same with algebra ? the geometric way is what i showed.

Comment: Given two points on the line, i can get the slope m. tan-1(m) will give me the angle of the line() with x-axis. Then 90-angle will give me the angle between two lines. right?

Comment: @monica correct, but if i need a single formula then i would do this instead. Lets say I have a Line $y = m(x - c)$ and another line $x = a$, then i can find the intersection of those two line Say point $H$ , intersection of line 1 with $x$ - axis, point $C$  and intersection of line 2 with $x$ - axis point $A$. With this i can find $CH$ and $AC$ . Then $tan(\theta)$ = $\frac{AC}{CH}$, where $\theta$ is the angle between the lines.

Answer (score 1):

In that case, the line is of the form $x = a$ for some number $a$. So the point of intersection of the two lines must satisfy this equation. In other words, the point of intersection must have an $x$-value of $a$. So just plug $x=a$ into the equation for the other line and you will get the $y$-value of the point of intersection, and then you'll be done.

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively (but not rigorously), you can consider the slope to be infinite. Then for the equation $y=m(x-p_x)+p_y$ to keep some meaning, you need to have $x-p_x=0$, so that $m(x-p_x)$ is indeterminate ($\infty\cdot0$) and $y$ can take any value.

Another way to look at it is to temporarily swap the two axis and work with $x=m'(y-p_y)+p_x$. Then the line is horizontal instead of vertical and you can solve with $m'=0$, i.e. $x=p_x$.