# You're given two lines with their two coordinates each, how to find the coordinate at they will eventually meet?

Tags: linear-algebra, coordinate-systems

Assuming the lines are not parallel and coinciding. So a similar to this;

[image]

So with those four coordinates only, how to find (a,b)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Do you know how to find the equation of a line containing two given points?

Comment: This might help: [Finding the equation of straight line](https://www.ugrad.math.ubc.ca/coursedoc/math100/notes/zoo/eqline.html), [Finding the intersection of straight lines](https://www.mathopenref.com/coordintersection.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find intersection point of two straight lines](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1798037/find-intersection-point-of-two-straight-lines)

Comment: @John Omielan Well in that question, it's said that one of the lines are parallel to the x-axis.

Comment: @RickAnders Yes, you're right. It's not a complete duplicate, but it does address the possibility that one of the lines is parallel to the $x$-axis, which you don't state but could be an issue for you as well. Also, at least the accepted answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1798084 shows the general technique you can use for your problem.

Comment: @RickAnders On further thought, perhaps it not similar enough to what you're specifically asking for it to be be considered a duplicate, so I'm retracting my vote to close as a duplicate.

Comment: Working in homogeneous coordinates, you can find the intersection with three cross products. This method works regardless of the orientation or parallelism of the line segments. If they are parallel, the intersection of their extensions is a point at infinity.

Answer (score 1):

The equation of the first line is $$ y - y_1 = \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2-x_1}\left(x - x_1 \right) $$ and similarly of the second line is $$ y - y_3 = \frac{y_4 - y_3}{x_4-x_3}\left(x - x_3 \right) $$ equating $y$-values at the intersection point gives us the linear equation in $x$ $$y_1 + \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2-x_1}\left(x - x_1 \right) = y_3 + \frac{y_4 - y_3}{x_4-x_3}\left(x - x_3 \right) $$ Can you take it from here?